# OData with EF and automapper: Cannot compare..'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported

Tags: automapper

Had an Odata v3 endpoint with ef 6.1.3 and automapper 6.1.1.

Datamodel,

- Order, one to many with Orderlines

  public partial class Order
  {
      [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
      public Order()
      {
          this.OrderLines = new HashSet();
      }

  ```
  public System.Guid OrderID { get; set; }
  public string OrderPlacedBy { get; set; }
  public Nullable<System.DateTime> PlacedTime { get; set; }

  [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
  public virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
  ```

  }
- OrderLines

  public partial class OrderLine
      {
          public System.Guid OrderLineID { get; set; }
          public Nullable OrderID { get; set; }
          public Nullable Amount { get; set; }

  ```
      public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
  }
  ```

AutoMapper code,

```
cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
                cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
                cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
                cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
                cfg.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("DTO_");

                cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>()
                    .ForMember(d=>d.OrderLines,o=>o.AllowNull())
                    .ForMember(d=>d.OrderLines,o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.OrderLines));
                cfg.CreateMap<OrderLine, OrderLineDTO>();
            });
```

Now if I browse the URL by

> http://localhost:34354/odata/Order?$expand=OrderLines

It is complaining with error below

> Cannot compare 'member 'OrderLines' of type 'c4codata.OrderDTO''. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.

What did I did wrong? This has struggled me for days, please help!!

I've uploaded the repo to https://github.com/ninithepug/odata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, you're using database first. All the AM tests use code first and that's what actually works. So you should do too. [Working gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/e1d5f819c43a6c2519643aba588300ac).

Comment: Thanks, I cannot use code first as database model cannot change.. I'll test the code u shared thanks for help!!

Comment: Also saw this seems exact issue with mine howeve still doesn't work..https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/925

Comment: Nobody said to change the database. You can write your entities so they match the existing database.

Comment: okay I run the code it is working, but if I put the same code in OData (v3) it is returning the same error.. so it is not helping..

Comment: If you can reduce it to a problem involving only AM, I'll take a look. I don't really care about the rest.